# Heating and Chilling ICs instantly from 200C to 0C? Does it damage the silicon inside?

Tags: integrated-circuit, soldering, heat, cooling

I soldered VCXO oscillator and suddenly tried to cool it down with a cooler spray. Do you think that sudden cooling and heating damages the chip. The heating and cooling were well within the spec requirement but I don't know if the sudden change in temperature of the device damages the IC inside the oscillator.

Comment: It is good to realize that a crystal oscillator is (partially at least) a mechanical part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically, you can introduce thermal shock that can crack an IC's casing, or cause bond wires to break off. Depending on how close the heating and freezing is and where the heat and cold is introduce, it can cause flexing from the different thermal expansions.

In practice though, it's hard to say if it has or has not happened. It might require a couple of cold/hot cycles to affect it. It depends on how fast the IC parts actually change in temperature. It depends on the temperatures it reaches. It depends on the IC's casing's thermal resistance.

You need to test it, and next time, avoid drastic temperature changes.

Comment: While I have your attention, it looks like your nomination got cut off: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/election/3#post-101015